# Find text that are no inside of another text string?

Tags: regex, go

Say I have some template text with placeholders like below:

```
Message: {{ .response.message }}  
More results: {{ .response.has_more_results }}. 
Results: 
{{range .response.results}}
   Contact name: {{.admin_contact.name.value}}
{{end}}
```

I'd like to create a regex that will extract the placeholders that *are not* inside of a `{{range ...}} .... {{end}}` section.  So in the above example I'd like to get `.response.message` and `.response.has_more_results`.

I came up with the following regex: `{{\s?(\.\S*?)\s?}}` but this also pulls in `.admin_contact.name.value` which I would like to exclude.

How can I use regex to pull only the placeholders that are outside of the `range` sections?

Comment: That'll require matching begin/end constructs like `range` and `if`, potentially nested, thus you'll need something more powerful than a regex.  You can parse the template, and use the parsed tree in the Template struct to process the tree yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a regex pattern that will match what you do not need and *capture* into Group 1 those substrings you need to extract:

```
(?s){{range.*?}}.*?{{end}}|{{\s*(\.[^\s{}]+)\s*}}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rEcsb3/1)

**Details**

- `(?s){{range.*?}}.*?{{end}}` - `(?s)` enables a `.` to match line break chars, `{{range` matches `{{range`, `.*?` matches any 0+ chars as few as possible, and then `{{end}}` matches a literal string
- `|` - or
- `{{` - `{{` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\.[^\s{}]+)` - Group 1: a `.` and then any 1+ chars other than whitespace, `{` and `}`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `}}` - a `}}` substring.

[Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/zUQG0KB2Doc):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {

    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?s){{range.*?}}.*?{{end}}|{{\s*(\.[^\s{}]+)\s*}}`)
    str := "Message: {{ .response.message }}  \nMore results: {{ .response.has_more_results }}. \nResults: \n{{range .response.results}}\n   Contact name: {{.admin_contact.name.value}}\n{{end}}"
    for _, match := range re.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1) {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", match[1])
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.response.message
.response.has_more_results
```

Comment: @BurakSerdar There are no nested ranges in the input.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Extending this type of expression to match (properly) nested placeholders is possible; something like `(?s)({{range\b[^}]*}}(?>.*?(?1))*.*?{{end}})|{{ (\.\S+) }}` would do. Whether this is advisable, I guess, depends on the use case.

Comment: If you need to use a regex for recursive templates, then you will need to install a PCRE supporting package and use something like `(?s)({{range.*?}}(?>(?!{{(?:range|end}})).|(?1)){{end}})|{{\s*(\.[^\s{}]+)\s*}}`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rEcsb3/3). Native Go regexp library, RE2, does not support recursion. However, the question itself sounds as "***Find text that are no inside of another text string***" without mentioning any recursion neither in the title, nor in the body, nor in the input sample text.